# Django API: Updating a list of dictionaries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to pass a list of dictionaries through my django rest framework API, loop through them, update the associated records in the model, and ultimately return the serialized data to the front end.

I am receiving the following error when submitting the list of dictionaries:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: PUT, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."
        ]
    },
    {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the JSON I'm passing through the django rest framework API template:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "order": "5"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "order": "3"
    }
]
```

Here is a view of my model:

```
class Waitlist(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    identification = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, validators=[], blank=True)
    mobile_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)

    store_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Here is a stripped down view of my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Waitlist

from .serializers import WaitlistOrderSerializer, WaitlistOrderListSerializer

@api_view(['PUT'])
def waitlistOrder(request):
    waitlist_data = request.data
    waitlist = []
    for data in waitlist_data:
        waitlist_id = data.get('id')
        w = Waitlist.objects.get(id=waitlist_id)
        waitlist.append(w)
    serializer = WaitlistOrderListSerializer(
        waitlist, data=waitlist_data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'success': 'Waitlist order updated successfully'})
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And, here is a stripped down view of my my serializers.py

```
class WaitlistOrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    order = serializers.IntegerField()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.order = validated_data.get('order', instance.order)
        instance.save()
        return instance


class WaitlistOrderListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = WaitlistOrderSerializer()

    def update(self, instances, validated_data):
        for instance, data in zip(instances, validated_data):
            self.child.update(instance, data)
        return instances
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at this line:

```
serializer = WaitlistOrderListSerializer(
        waitlist, data=waitlist_data, many=True)
```

It should be:

```
serializer = WaitlistOrderListSerializer(waitlist)
```

But there is no need to create `ListSerializer`. When you pass `many=True`, this `ListSerializer` is automatically created and `WaitlistOrderSerializer` will be passed as a child. Similar to what you you are doing.

So you can do:

```
serializer = WaitlistOrderSerializer(waitlist, many=True)
```

and remove your listserializer entirely.